# Is there a way to convert a string (format: "1,5,20,22") to an array of integers ( [1,5, 20, 22] ) during MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, metabase

I have been working with **MongoDB** (and [**Metabase**](https://metabase.com)). **Metabase** way of searching is based on **Mongo** aggregation pipelines.

For people that don't know, **Metabase** allows us to create **charts**, and you can define filters for those charts, and use those filters on your **Mongo** query.

Anyway, the only filter types I can have are: **String**, **Number** and **Date**.

But, I have a query, that I need to check if a field value is **$in** some array.

So, I am not able to send an array as a filter.
Single number wouldn't work.

My idea was to pass a **String** (format: **"1,3,5,20"**), then transform this string in an array of numbers.

Is there a simple way to do this in a single "shot" on Mongo Aggregation?
I am trying to not rely on multiple pipeline stages

I know I can use [split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) to generate my array, but from there, I would need to transform all values on my new array of string in integer values.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html#map-aggregation), perhaps:

```
{$project:{
   arrayField: {$map: {
      input: {$split: ["$stringField",","]},
      as: "elem",
      in: {$toInt: "$$elem"}
   }}
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KXaWZJosRp9)